# Calling an object from an API in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, asynchronous

[This is my current result of this task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x93hj.png)**Please see the problematic lines comment. I'm having trouble getting the values of the currencies and languages from the API. I tried using ${data.currencies[0].name} and ${data.languages[0].name} but it still throws an error. **

```js
'use strict';

const btn = document.querySelector('.btn-country');
const countriesContainer = document.querySelector('.countries');

///////////////////////////////////////
const getCountryData = function(country){
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // GET DATA
    request.open('GET', `https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/${country}`);
    
    // SEND THE REQUEST
    request.send();
    
    // REGISTER A CALLBACK FUNCTION ON THE REQUEST OBJECT FOR THE LOAD EVENT
    request.addEventListener('load', function(){
        // CONVERT JSON CODE TO A JAVASCRIPT OBJECT 
        const [data]= JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    
        // ([data] is being destructured because it was an array that had an object in it, so now its just an object containing all the information)
    
        console.log(data);
    
        const html = `
        <article class="country">
        <img class="country__img" src="${data.flags.png}" />
        <div class="country__data">
          <h3 class="country__name">${data.name.common}</h3>
          <h4 class="country__region">${data.region}</h4>
          <p class="country__row"><span></span>${(+data.population / 1000000).toFixed(1)} million</p>
          <p class="country__row"><span>️</span>${data.languages}</p> //problematic line
          <p class="country__row"><span></span>${data.currencies.name}</p> //problematic line
        </div>
      </article>
        `;
        countriesContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
        countriesContainer.style.opacity = 1;
    });
};

getCountryData('nigeria');
getCountryData('south africa');
```

Comment: both `currencies` and `languages` in `data` hold objects not arrays

Comment: Add the event listener **before** sending the message.

Comment: I know its an object, but how do I call it from the API

Comment: @ChiomaUche ... For iterating/accessing an **object**'s **entries** and/or **values** like with what the OP struggles (e.g. `currencies `,  `languages `) there is [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) respectively [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values).